# How to retrieve and compare data from local database?

Tags: android

I'm new to Programming in general, and i have hit a problem. I was trying to check whether my inputs are conflicting with another value that is already inside my local database.

```
private void CheckData (){

   final EditText txtSubjectCode           = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.subjectcode_et);
   final EditText txtSubjectDescription    = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.subjdesc_et);
   final EditText txtSection               = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.section_et);
   final EditText txtRoom                  = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.room_et);
   final EditText txtTime                  = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtTimeS);
   final EditText txttime1                 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtTimeF);

   final String subjectCode                = txtSubjectCode.getText().toString().toUpperCase();
   final String section                    = txtSection.getText().toString().toUpperCase();
   final String subjectdescription         = txtSubjectDescription.getText().toString().toUpperCase();
   final String room                       = txtRoom.getText().toString().toUpperCase();
   final String timestart                  = txtTime.getText().toString().toUpperCase();
   final String timeend                    = txttime1.getText().toString().toUpperCase();

   subjectcode         = new ArrayList();
   Section             = new ArrayList();
   Subjectdescription  = new ArrayList();
   Room                = new ArrayList();
   Timestart           = new ArrayList();
   Timeend             = new ArrayList();

   subjectcode.clear();
   Section.clear();
   Subjectdescription.clear();
   Room.clear();
   Timestart.clear();
   Timeend.clear();

   String qu = "SELECT * FROM PSCHEDULE";
   Cursor cursor = SplashActivity.handler.execQuery(qu);

   if (cursor == null || cursor.getCount() == 0) {
       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Schedule Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       cursor.moveToFirst();
       while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {

           subjectcode.add(cursor.getString(0));
           Section.add(cursor.getString(1));
           Subjectdescription.add(cursor.getString(2));
           Room.add(cursor.getString(3));
           Timestart.add(cursor.getString(4));
           Timeend.add(cursor.getString(5));

           cursor.moveToNext();
       }
   } else {
        String qu1 = " INSERT INTO PSCHEDULE(subjectcode, section, subjectdescription, room, timestart, timeend) VALUES('" + subjectCode +
            "',"+ "'" + section +
            "',"+ "'" + subjectdescription +
            "',"+ "'" + room +
            "',"+ "'" + timestart +
            "',"+ "'" + timeend + "');";

        if(SplashActivity.handler.execAction(qu1)) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Schedule Saved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            this.finish();
        }
   }
}
```

It only return out of bounds error with 0 index and 0 size. How do I retrieve data from my database and compare it with my input. Thank you.

Comment: `if (cursor == null || cursor.getCount() == 0) { ... cursor.moveToFirst(); }` If cursor is null or has nothing, you can't "moveToFirst".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my general observation you are placing the if conditions wrongly. You are trying to get the data from `cursor` when it is `null` or empty. So I think you need to swap your logic or fix the if statement like this.

```
if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Schedule Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   cursor.moveToFirst();

   while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
       subjectCodeList.add(cursor.getString(0));
       Section.add(cursor.getString(1));
       Subjectdescription.add(cursor.getString(2));
       Room.add(cursor.getString(3));
       Timestart.add(cursor.getString(4));
       Timeend.add(cursor.getString(5));

       cursor.moveToNext();
   }

   // Compare the result got from cursor here. 
   for (String code : subjectCodeList) {
       if(code.equals(subjectCode)) {
           Toast.makeText(this, "Already exists", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           break;
       }
   }

} else {
   String qu1 = " INSERT INTO PSCHEDULE(subjectcode, section, subjectdescription, room, timestart, timeend) VALUES('" + subjectCode +
       "',"+ "'" + section +
       "',"+ "'" + subjectdescription +
       "',"+ "'" + room +
       "',"+ "'" + timestart +
       "',"+ "'" + timeend + "');";

   if(SplashActivity.handler.execAction(qu1)) {
       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Schedule Saved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       this.finish();
   }
}
```

**Update**

Once you have put all the data in respective `ArrayList`, you will now traverse the `ArrayList` and compare with each item if the item is equals to the value you have got from your `EditText`. See the updated code above for a sample checking.

When you are initializing your `ArrayList`, you are not setting any specific type. The initializations should look like the following.

```
ArrayList<String> subjectCodeList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> sectionList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> subjectDescriptionList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> roomList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Long> timeStartList = new ArrayList<>();   
ArrayList<Long> timeEndList = new ArrayList<>();
```

You need to execute the query that you have generated.

```
else {
   String qu1 = " INSERT INTO PSCHEDULE(subjectcode, section, subjectdescription, room, timestart, timeend) VALUES('" + subjectCode +
       "',"+ "'" + section +
       "',"+ "'" + subjectdescription +
       "',"+ "'" + room +
       "',"+ "'" + timestart +
       "',"+ "'" + timeend + "');";

   // You need to execute the query in your database here
   db.execQuery(qu1);

   if(SplashActivity.handler.execAction(qu1)) {
       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Schedule Saved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       this.finish();
   }
```

Comment: Thank you! it works now but how do i compare the data from the table with inputted values?

Comment: In the for loop that you give sir, It's displaying an incompatible type of Object was needed and but String was given. do I change the string to an Object?

Comment: Please see the updated answer. You need to modify your `ArrayList` initializers.

Comment: I guess this is my last question, The code you updated works thank you. But its not saving new entries, do i move my else statement to be able to execute the code?

Comment: This is because you did not execute the query. You just have built the query string. You did not execute it. Please see the updated answer again.